# Java long cannot be cast to string

Tags: java, casting

I've created a program that saves and loads BigInteger and String variables. When I've started the program it shows that exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String

And it says it happens here:

`robotPrices[0] = new BigInteger(sharedPreferences.getString("rbt1price", "100"));`

My saving method:

```
public void save() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    editor.putString("rbt1price", robotPrices[0].toString());
    editor.putString("rbt2price", robotPrices[1].toString());
    editor.putString("rbt3price", robotPrices[2].toString());
    editor.putString("rbt4price", robotPrices[3].toString());
    editor.putString("rbt5price", robotPrices[4].toString());
    editor.putString("rbt1qu", robotQu[0].toString());
    editor.putString("rbt2qu", robotQu[1].toString());
    editor.putString("rbt3qu", robotQu[2].toString());
    editor.putString("rbt4qu", robotQu[3].toString());
    editor.putString("rbt5qu", robotQu[4].toString());

    editor.putLong("lvl", lvl);
    editor.apply();
}
```

My loading method:

```
private void load() {


SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    lvl = sharedPreferences.getLong("lvl", 1);

    robotPrices[0] = new BigInteger(sharedPreferences.getString("rbt1price", "100"));
    robotPrices[1] = new BigInteger(sharedPreferences.getString("rbt2price", "1100"));
    robotPrices[2] = new BigInteger(sharedPreferences.getString("rbt3price", "12000"));
    robotPrices[3] = new BigInteger(sharedPreferences.getString("rbt4price", "130000"));
    robotPrices[4] = new BigInteger(sharedPreferences.getString("rbt5price", "1400000"));
    robotQu[0] = new BigInteger(sharedPreferences.getString("rbt1qu", "0"));
    robotQu[1] = new BigInteger(sharedPreferences.getString("rbt2qu", "0"));
    robotQu[2] = new BigInteger(sharedPreferences.getString("rbt3qu", "0"));
    robotQu[3] = new BigInteger(sharedPreferences.getString("rbt4qu", "0"));
    robotQu[4] = new BigInteger(sharedPreferences.getString("rbt5qu", "0"));
}
```

**Edit:**
THIS doesn't work too:

```
robotPrices[0] = new BigInteger(sharedPreferences.getLong("rbt1price", 100));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found it was kind of bug in android studio (or java compiler). I just needed to add
`String rp0 = sharedPreferences.getString("rbt1price", "100");`
and everything works. So, I did not, as some told me, "violate java's rules".
Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 2):

from [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

> Throws ClassCastException if there is a preference with this name that is not a String.

It appears that you should use getLong() instead of getString().

Comment: But I need String value for BigInteger constructor, not a long value

Comment: You aren't going to get it by violating Java's rules. Have you considered reading the `BigInteger` documentation? Why not? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#valueOf-long-

Comment: But I saved this value as String not as long so I can't getLong() where i have String